# Linux file system location immutable files

Tags: linux

I have a file that is generated on image creation and describes the structure of the image. The file could be changed at runtime - but it doesn't make sense, because the changes won't be reflected in the system.

Where to place this file in the linux directory structure?

- `/etc`: This implies to me that it is a configuration that could be changed in system operation. Does not fit.
- `/var`: This implies that the files are changed at runtime. Does not fit.
- `/proc`: Makes most sense to me - arbitrary files that describe the system state. But many of the files are also changed at runtime.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)?

Comment: `/proc` is useless, here usually is dynamic filesystem mounted, you can't place any "real" files here that should survive a reboot.

Comment: I think that is in the category, wherever makes sense for you. IIRC some installers place a record/config file with the options selected at install time in `/root` (i.e. RHEL, Fedora)  or consider such info a "log" and use for example /`var/log/installer` and alternatively  the FHS location for persistently storing "state" is `/var/lib/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard version 3.0 (published in 2015) says this about `/etc`:

> 3.7. /etc : Host-specific system configuration
>
> 3.7.1. Purpose
> The /etc hierarchy contains configuration files. A "configuration file" is a local file used to control the operation of a program; it must be static and cannot be an executable binary.
>
> It is recommended that files be stored in subdirectories of /etc rather than directly in /etc.
>
> 3.7.2. Requirements
> No binaries may be located under /etc.

Note that **there is no requirement nor implication that the files need to be changeable in system operation.**

There are also practical precedents: many distributions place a file that identifies the name and version of the distribution into `/etc`: `/etc/redhat-release` for RHEL, `/etc/SuSE-release` for SuSE, `/etc/debian_version` for Debian, and so on. Such files are normally only updated by the package management system, when significant patch level updates are installed. On systems maintained "cloud-style" by reloading complete system images, those files would still be expected to be present, but would effectively never change during a particular image's lifetime - just like your image description file.

If you want to make it explicit that the image description file is not to be changed, you could use `chattr +i` to mark it as *immutable* (assuming that you use a filesystem type that supports the attribute). After that, it requires a deliberate, rarely-used privileged command to make the file changeable again.